# Why does open("file", "w") not block?

Tags: python, windows, ntfs

I am on Windows using NTFS and I have 2 processes opening the same file in write mode (`w`). I was surprised to see, that both succeed. Am I missing someething? I thought write mode implicitly has a file-lock on the handle until the file is opened again (unless opened in a shared-write) mode?

Process 1:

```
fp = open("file.txt", "w")
time.sleep(10000)
```

Process 2:

```
fp = open("file.txt", "w")
time.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: Why would you assume an implicit file lock?

Comment: Perhaps it's intrinsic to another language you're familiar with. No such luck here, sorry

Comment: @roganjosh I doubt this would be language-specific as opposed to depending on kernel implementation, but yeah. I have never seen such lock being implemented.

Comment: Perhaps it's because neither process is attempting to write to the file.

Comment: Wow, years of assumption how filehandles work just went straight out the window. In my case I even tried writing the file in a loop, still both loops go through, but only one really ends up in the file, the other one ends in nowhere

Comment: Imagine I write a huge file to disk, I always have seen error messages on Windows as this file cannot be written because its still used by another process. I kind of assumed that's the error message of `GetLastError()` when opening a file that is written by another process

Comment: Any background information for Unix/MacOS or Linux would be helpful either

Comment: Well, is that going to answer your problem or do you just need a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) ? I'm unlikely to answer either way because I don't think I know enough, but maybe you'd get something more practical searching around that?

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately `semaphores` are used for a different purpose, and wouldn't really fix my issue. But I will look more into file locking now

Comment: Popping up a level... what are you >trying to do<??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the implementation of your open() function must be passing FILE_SHARED_WRITE to the kernel. Otherwise, one of the calls would return an error, not block.